# What does "that uniform is a trip" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

*trip* means *weird*? It occurs in the movie *Forrest Gump*. I think Jenny is trying to imply that Forrest has have made some journey to obtain that uniform.

```
           EXT. WASHINGTON D.C. - NIGHT

           Forrest and Jenny walk past the White House. Protesters hold 
           a candlelight vigil behind them.


           They walk in silence. Jenny touches Forrest's uniform.

                                 JENNY
                     That uniform is a trip, Forrest. You 
                     look handsome in it. You do.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember that part of the movie.

Jenny was a hippie and did not get exposed to soldiers with the type of life she was living.  Hippies generally disagreed with the war going on in Vietnam and had nothing in common and very little respect with the soldiers doing the fighting.

When she saw Forest dressed in the uniform the word "trip" was meant as disbelief that her friend was dressed in the clothes of one of the people she is actively protesting against.

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with that segment of the movie, but it sounds like

> trip

is being used as slang to describe something that is *outrageous*

> That story was a real *trip*.
>   *that story was really strange / weird / fantastic*

it comes from the 1960's when people hallucinated on LSD which was called *a trip* or *tripping*